# Couchdb replication hangs and doesn't proceed

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to replicate some couchdb databases. It works perfectly fine for all, except for one. It seems to always stay stuck at some point in the replication, and the terminal forever stays on hold and doesn't return.
I have no idea where the problem comes from, I imagine it could be one specific document that is problematic, but I don't know how I could check and debug that.
Also, I noticed that if I use replicator in futon, it seems to be working and replicate. But I need to be able to do it from the command line.
Any idea where the problem could be coming from or/and how to debug it?

This is the command I'm using:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate -d '{"source":"http://user:password@127.0.0.1:5984/origin-db-name", "target":"http://user:password@127.0.0.1:5984/target-db-name"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

and here is the output I get when running: curl `"http://user:password@127.0.0.1:5984/_active_tasks"`:

```
[
  {
    "pid":"<0.351.0>",
    "checkpoint_interval":5000,
    "checkpointed_source_seq":1007,
    "continuous":false,
    "doc_id":null, 
    "doc_write_failures":0,
    "docs_read":0,
    "docs_written":0,
    "missing_revisions_found":0,
    "progress":59,
    "replication_id":"4ec403b2de1d9c546182252369f1d96e",
    "revisions_checked":187,
    "source":"http://user:*****@127.0.0.1:5984/origin-db-name/",
    "source_seq":1693,
    "started_on":1531010162,
    "target":"http://user:*****@127.0.0.1:5984/target-db-name/",
    "type":"replication",
    "updated_on":1531010188
  }
]
```